# how to create relationship in laravel by model id and model types

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

*I have a table that is associated with one, using their id and id table type*

table 1

*id,
type_id,
type,
count, 
crteated_at, 
updated_at*

other tables

*id name, ....... crteated_at updated_at*

model type ids

model2 = type_id = 2;
model3 = type_id = 3;

> In model 1

```
public function model2()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(model2::class, 'type_id', 'id');
}

public function model3()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(model3::class, 'type_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: kindly be more clear in your question it confusing :-) can you share your table schema

Comment: I have a common table referenced by many other tables, type_id is the identifier of the row from these tables, and column type, as it were, the identifier by which  is calculating by other table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a Polymorphic Relation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: yes, but I do not need to specify the name of the model,  i do need to specify  id which I set in the configuration file

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getModel(Request $request){

      if($request->get('model_type')==1){
       $mod = 'Model1'
       }
       if($request->get('model_type')==2){
         $mod = 'Model'
       }  

      $obj = new {Mod}()
      $result = $obj->get();

      return $result       
 }
```

I would do so